# Is there a way to navigate to three or four levels inside navigation view using NavigationLink?

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

Update: apparently there is a problem with navigationLink in navigationBarItems here is the working code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showForm: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button("Start Form", action: { showForm.toggle() })
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showForm) {
            FormView()
        }
    }
}

struct FormView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var closeButton: some View {
        Button(action: { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() } ) { Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill") }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(formPM: presentationMode)) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Form", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: closeButton)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    @Binding var formPM: PresentationMode
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var closeButton: some View {
        Button(action: { formPM.dismiss() } ) { Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill") }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Button(action: { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() } ) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView(formPM: $formPM)) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Second", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: closeButton)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    @Binding var formPM: PresentationMode
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var closeButton: some View {
        Button(action: { formPM.dismiss() } ) { Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill") }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Button(action: { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() } ) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Third", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: closeButton)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

and example:

[image: example]

here is a sample code I could not get it to work,

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showForm: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button("Start Form", action: { showForm.toggle() })
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showForm) {
            FormView()
        }
    }
}

struct FormView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var closeButton: some View {
        Button(action: { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() } ) {
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
        }
    }
    
    var navButtons: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(presentationMode: presentationMode)) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Text("FORM")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Form", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: closeButton, trailing: navButtons)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    @Binding var presentationMode: PresentationMode
    
    var closeButton: some View {
        Button(action: { presentationMode.dismiss() } ) {
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
        }
    }
    
    var navButtons: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: FormView()) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView(presentationMode: $presentationMode)) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("SECOND")
            .navigationBarTitle("Second", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: closeButton, trailing: navButtons)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    @Binding var presentationMode: PresentationMode
    
    var closeButton: some View {
        Button(action: { presentationMode.dismiss() } ) {
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
        }
    }
    
    var navButtons: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(presentationMode: $presentationMode)) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("THIRD")
            .navigationBarTitle("Third", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: closeButton, trailing: navButtons)
    }
}
```

it is a full screen sheet form with 3 pages, with next and back buttons, here is my problems:

- I can't navigate from second view to third view.
- I can't navigate back from second view to form view or from third view to second view.

any idea is appreciated,
thank you

Comment: You misunderstood sense of NavigationLink - it navigates to destination only forward, backward navigation is possible either by back button or when binding of navigationlink (either isAction or selection) is deactivated programmatically. Note that presentation mode destroys entire navigation state, so you go to root from whichever place it dismissed.

Comment: @pawello2222 yes it does thank you I will update my post with new code, hope it helps anyone